# materialize css datepicker yearRange not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, material-design

I am using materialize css datepicker . i need to select yearRange from 1950 to 2005 but yearRange is not working yearRange is also showing drop down future years iam using following code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker(
       {

    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
     maxDate: new Date(),

     selectMonths: true,


changeMonth: true,

changeYear: true,

  yearRange: 100,

     });
```

if i change yearRange to negative (i.e yearRange:-100) in date picker year dropdown not working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prashanthviru/vofo0rsz/  check this fiddle

Comment: any one can able to find the answer @raffa

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation you have to provide a number or array. Its a bit confusing because in case of numbers you specify how many years from current year should be in the dropdown. For example, `yearRange: 10` means 10 years back (2008) and 10 years forward (2028).

But when you specify the array, you specify actual years, so for your case the correct options are

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
  yearRange: [1950,2005],
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
});
```